# Transfering music files to new android phone

Tags: android, music

I am using Ubuntu 22.04. I recently purchased a new Android phone, a Pixel 6. I am trying to transfer my music files to the new phone, but I cannot seem to make it work.

I have tried plugging the phone by usb cable into my PC. Nautilus recognizes the phone, but cannot see its file system.

I have loaded my music onto Google drive, but I cannot figure out how to download it onto the phone.

Are there any other file transfer apps suitable to this task that I am missing? I would greatly appreciate any help.

Stewart

Comment: Why don't you use Google Drive in the phone? It should be a no-brainer. Re: the only part of the question that is on-topic here, what option are you selecting in the phone after connecting the USB cable? Please [edit] the question accordingly.

Comment: Did you make sure that your Pixel under the settings for USB Preferences is set for `File Transfer / Android Auto`?  I think Pixels default to `No data transfer`.

Comment: Transfering files over USB is painfully slow (it uses an extremely flawed Microsoft based transfer protocol). If you still have the old phone and if the old phone still works, you want to find an app that allows transfer of files over wifi. Maybe ask this question on https://android.stackexchange.com to find an app or a way to transfer the files over wifi or how to download the files after they are transferred to Google Drive.

Comment: For my Pixel 3a (yes I know it is old!) I simply use Bluetooth...

Comment: Thank you all for your comments, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments, but nothing seems to work. 

Google Drive  - I have it in my phone and I can see the files, but I just cannot transfer them from drive to the phone.

Comment: USB file transfer settings i this is not as easy as it sounds. I followed these instructions:
Change USB Configuration:
A setting in your phone lets you determine the default action for your phone when it is connected to a PC via a USB cable. By default, it is set to No Data transfer, and if it stays like that, you won’t be able to transfer anything between your PC and phone. To fix this, you need to change this setting.

Comment: Open up Settings on your Pixel 6/ Pixel 6 Pro and go to About.
There tap on the Build number 7 times. You will see a pop-up on your screen that reads, “You are now a developer.”
Afterward, go back to the Settings main page and navigate to System.
Inside System, you will find the option Developer Options.
Inside Developer Options, go to USB configuration and change it to File Transfer.
After this, you should be able to transfer files between your Pixel 6/ Pixel 6 Pro and your PC. If you still cannot do so, try the next solution.

Comment: When I tried it out, permission to copy files was denied, and I cannot figure out how to change that.

Bluetooth - my PC and the phone are paired. Now what? How do I  make the transfer?

I feel like a Linux neophyte here and I really need some step-by-step instructions. Again, many thanks for all your help.

Comment: I have no idea where you got your instructions from.  I have a Google Pixel 6 Pro, and all I had to do was go to Settings, then I searched for USB Preferences.  Plugged in my phone to my Ubuntu installation, selected File Transfer / Android Auto, and my full files came up in my file browser.  I use Thunar.  Plus, I cannot enable debugging mode on my phone since it is controlled by the company I work for, but file browsing was not an issue.  If you get a permission that pops up on your phone after plugging in, make sure you click Approve on it.

Comment: Your solution worked perfectly. The critical part was Thunar, which I now have and will remember. Many thanks!